# pd.read_excel does recognize the file but does not actually read it

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've been busy working on some code and one part of it is importing an excel file. I've been using the code below. Now, on one pc it works but on another it does not (I did change the paths though). Python does recognize the excel file and does not give an error when loading, but when I print the table it says:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Just to be sure, I checked the filepath which seems to be correct. I also checked the sheetname but that is all good too.

```
df = pd.read_excel(book_filepath, sheet_name='Potentie_alles')
description = df["#"].map(str)
```

The key error '#' (# is the header of the first column of the sheet).
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Kind regards,
iCookieMonster

Comment: did you at first test sth like `print(df.head())`? This should return the first few lines including headers and index of the dataframe, so you can easily examine how it is represented. (May I guess that `#` is the header of the first column which was used as the index? So perhaps try `df.index`...)

Comment: It returns the same: Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: []. What confuses me is that reading the excel file does not give an error, but the dataframe is just empty.

Comment: but you did double check, that the excel file version on the other pc isn't simply empty...? At least the sheet named `'Potentie_alles'`?

Comment: On one pc I use Windows Excel and on the other one OpenOffice, could that cause trouble?

Comment: Yes, I just triple checked :)

Comment: Shouldn't have anything to do with your problem, as you don't want to use either of these SW tools, but rather access the file via pandas...

Comment: Is it really the only file there? One idea would be (because of your hint that you use MSXL and OOCalc), that perhaps you have two files with the same name but different endings in your folder (one xls and one ods - and one is empty...)

Comment: Next check: both pandas versions up to date (or at least equal)?

Comment: Ah one the pc where the script is working it's version 0.23.4, on the other one it is 0.20.3. I'll update pandas and then report back!

Comment: Final update: updating all packages to the same version worken. Unfortunately, I upgraded all packages at the same time so I am not sure which package was causing trouble.